# NullpointerException when converting String to double in java

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, double

I have an html form which contains a `String` which I need to convert into a `double`. Then store it in an MS Access database.  I tried using:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(String);
```

But it is throwing a NullpointerException. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) reveals that `Double.parseDouble` throws a `NullPointerException` if the argument is `null`.